# Custom event in user control

Tags: vb.net, events, controls

I've got a page (aspx) that contains a usercontrol (ascx).  On postback of the aspx, I'd like to read some control values in the ascx.  So upon reading some [good articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972975.aspx), I created an event in my aspx that fires on postback.  The event handler is in the ascx, and simply writes the values I'm interested in to the viewstate so that the parent page can read them.
The problem is my event handler never gets hit, even though I see the event is raised as I step through the code.  So my code bombs when trying to read the viewstate (which is empty)

Here's what I've got in my aspx:

```
Partial Public Class Visitor
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Public Event PagePostback(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
.
.
.
    Private Sub SaveAssignment(ByVal e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent PagePostback(Me, e) 'Tell usercontrol to post its control values to the viewstate
    'read viewstate and save its values
    End Sub
```

Here's what's in my ascx:

```
Partial Public Class GenVstr
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
    Protected WithEvents pageVisitor As Visitor
    Public Property visitType() As String
        Get
        Return ViewState("visitType").ToString
        End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        ViewState("visitType") = value
    End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub ParentPostback(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles pageVisitor.PagePostback
        With Me
        If optVIP.Checked Then .visitType = "VIP"
        If optFamily.Checked Then .visitType = "Family"
        If optMedia.Checked Then .visitType = "Media"
        If optGuest.Checked Then .visitType = "Guest"
        If optConference.Checked Then .visitType = "Conference"
        End With
    End Sub
```

Oh, did I happen to mention I'm dynamically loading the ascx?  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the problem.  It was in this line:

```
Public Sub ParentPostback(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles pageVisitor.PagePostback
```

Specifically in my Handles section, "pageVisitor" is the name of the variable I declared WithEvents.  Instead of handling that, I should have handled the name of my usercontrol (its ID) PagePostback event.

So it should look like this:

```
Public Sub ParentPostback(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles [myusercontrol's ID].PagePostback
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call addhandler on the dynamically create control when it is created.